# Crontab unable to run scripts?

Tags: cron

I have been googling and looking at this all day. I feel like there is something semi obvious that I am missing here. I am still a newbie when it comes to linux, and even more so when it comes to cron. Could one of you gurus help me find the solution?

cron entry

`1 * * * * /data/cronScripts/weeklyPageCreate.sh`

I want it to run every minute to confirm its going to run at all. So far, I have not seen any errors coming out in `/var/log/cron`

Script itself

```
#!/bin/bash

DATE_TODAY=$(/bin/date +'%Y-%m-%d')
DATE_TODAYMINUSFIVE=$(/bin/date +'%Y-%m-%d' -d '7 day ago')
#echo $DATE_TODAY
#echo $DATE_TODAYMINUSFIVE

curl -u 'user':'pass' -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"type":"page","title":"Weekly Report ('$DATE_TODAY')","ancestors":[{"id":316048939}], "space":{"key":"ITC"},"body":{"storage":{"value":"<ac:structured-macro ac:name=\"hideelements-macro\" ac:schema-version=\"1\"><ac:parameter ac:name=\"metas\">true</ac:parameter><ac:parameter ac:name=\"comments\">true</ac:parameter><ac:parameter ac:name=\"edit\">true</ac:parameter><ac:parameter ac:name=\"watch\">true</ac:parameter><ac:parameter ac:name=\"create\">true</ac:parameter><ac:parameter ac:name=\"favorite\">true</ac:parameter><ac:parameter ac:name=\"labels\">true</ac:parameter><ac:parameter ac:name=\"likes\">true</ac:parameter></ac:structured-macro><h1>B2B</h1><ac:structured-macro ac:name=\"jira\" ac:schema-version=\"1\"><ac:parameter ac:name=\"server\">JIRAAPPLINK</ac:parameter><ac:parameter ac:name=\"columns\">key,summary,created,assignee,reporter,resolution</ac:parameter><ac:parameter ac:name=\"maximumIssues\">20</ac:parameter><ac:parameter ac:name=\"jqlQuery\">project = AND resolved >= '$DATE_TODAYMINUSFIVE' AND resolved &lt;= '$DATE_TODAY' </ac:parameter><ac:parameter ac:name=\"serverId\">d9064433-ee34-3ef3-8b28-1606bcb513a1</ac:parameter></ac:structured-macro><h1>Data</h1><ac:structured-macro ac:name=\"jira\" ac:schema-version=\"1\"><ac:parameter ac:name=\"server\">JIRAAPPLINK</ac:parameter><ac:parameter ac:name=\"columns\">key,summary,created,assignee,reporter,resolution</ac:parameter><ac:parameter ac:name=\"maximumIssues\">20</ac:parameter><ac:parameter ac:name=\"jqlQuery\">project = AND resolved >= '$DATE_TODAYMINUSFIVE' AND resolved &lt;= '$DATE_TODAY' </ac:parameter><ac:parameter ac:name=\"serverId\">d9064433-ee34-3ef3-8b28-1606bcb513a1</ac:parameter></ac:structured-macro><h1>SalesForce</h1><ac:structured-macro ac:name=\"jira\" ac:schema-version=\"1\"><ac:parameter ac:name=\"server\">JIRAAPPLINK</ac:parameter><ac:parameter ac:name=\"columns\">key,summary,created,assignee,reporter,resolution</ac:parameter><ac:parameter ac:name=\"maximumIssues\">20</ac:parameter><ac:parameter ac:name=\"jqlQuery\">project =  AND resolved >= '$DATE_TODAYMINUSFIVE' AND resolved &lt;= '$DATE_TODAY' </ac:parameter><ac:parameter ac:name=\"serverId\">d9064433-ee34-3ef3-8b28-1606bcb513a1</ac:parameter></ac:structured-macro><h1>Oracle</h1><ac:structured-macro ac:name=\"jira\" ac:schema-version=\"1\"><ac:parameter ac:name=\"server\">JIRAAPPLINK</ac:parameter><ac:parameter ac:name=\"columns\">key,summary,created,assignee,reporter,resolution</ac:parameter><ac:parameter ac:name=\"maximumIssues\">20</ac:parameter><ac:parameter ac:name=\"jqlQuery\">project = Oracle AND resolved >= '$DATE_TODAYMINUSFIVE' AND resolved &lt;= '$DATE_TODAY' </ac:parameter><ac:parameter ac:name=\"serverId\">d9064433-ee34-3ef3-8b28-1606bcb513a1</ac:parameter></ac:structured-macro><ac:structured-macro ac:name=\"previous-next-navigation\" ac:schema-version=\"1\"><ac:parameter ac:name=\"next-button-text\">Next Week</ac:parameter><ac:parameter ac:name=\"previous-button-text\">Previous Week</ac:parameter><ac:parameter ac:name=\"button-style\">Primary</ac:parameter><ac:parameter ac:name=\"parent-button-text\">Directory</ac:parameter></ac:structured-macro>","representation":"storage"}}}' https://site.domain.com/rest/api/content | python -mjson.tool
```

This runs just fine from command line, and I have `chmod +x` on it.

I guess side question. There is `/etc/crontab` and then you can edit crontab with `crontab -e`, but was is the difference? Do both always run, and is there a reason you put jobs in one rather than the other?

Comment: what does the script do when you run from command line?

Comment: It returns a 200 response with a json dump of the page being create from the curl command. The script is used to create a page in the company internal wiki on a weekly basis pull stats from our issue tracker

Comment: If it does tasks that need admin level permissions then you will need to create that cron job using the command `sudo crontab -e`

Comment: Also, check cron service is running `service cron status`

Comment: When you say "what is the difference", what are you comparing with the `crontab -e` command?

Comment: @codlord that returns 'unit cron.service could not be found', but I can see in /var/log/cron that this crontab is being ran

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen I dont believe this needs to be an admin level thing. I will give it a shot though

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen I am comparing crontab -e to just using vi/nano to edit /etc/crontab

Comment: `1 * * * *` means the cronjob is run on the 1st minute of every hour.  It's not every minute.  `* * * * *` is every minute.  Could this be your problem?

Comment: @Nmath if that is true, possibly. Ill change this to * * * * *

Comment: I added that, and it is now running every minute. I see that the entry i put in crontab -e is running, but nothing shows up on my pages. I also added it in the /etc/crontab file, and I am not seeing that its erroring with (CRON) bad command (/etc/crontab)

Comment: So I dont know exactly what happened but now this is all working. I think it might be because I had this going every 1 hour, not every 1 minute! @Nmath if you want to make your comment an answer, I can mark it correct!

Comment: I think this lines `The  -e  option is used to edit the current crontab using the editor specified by the VISUAL or EDITOR environment
       variables.  After you exit from the editor, the modified crontab will be installed automatically.  If  neither  of
       the environment variables is defined, then the default editor /usr/bin/editor is used.` for `man crontab` might interest you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Your script is probably fine!

Your crontab instructions are not right:

`1 * * * * /data/cronScripts/weeklyPageCreate.sh` will not run every minute.

A *numeral* in any column represents the specific minute/hour/day/month/weekday when the cronjob is scheduled to run.

The `*` expression is the notation that stands for "all" or "every"

So `1 * * * *` will actually schedule the job to run on all weekdays, all months, every day, and every hour, at the first minute of each hour.  *ie. 4:01; 5:01; 6:01*

If you want the job to run every minute, you would use the notation `* * * * *`.  This means the job will scheduled for all weekdays, all months, every day, and every minute of every hour.

If you want your script to run every minute, the full crontab line should be:

```
* * * * * /data/cronScripts/weeklyPageCreate.sh
```

If you need help deciphering crontab notation in the future, use your favorite search engine and search for a "crontab calculator".  There are many out there!

Answer (score 1):

I would always ensure you output your scripts to script logs so something like

`1 * * * * /data/cronScripts/weeklyPageCreate.sh >> /path/to/weeklyPageCreate.log 2>&1`

That way you have a log of any errors/messages from that script to see if it's running or causing errors.

One common issue with cron is that the environment is not the same as a user shell environment so environment variables that may be present in your shell will not be present when the script is run in cron. So your scripts may need to explicitly set variables or source scripts to set variables etc.

Have a read here at the bottom for cron "gotchas":
https://www.pantz.org/software/cron/croninfo.html

Comment: So what is strange is that I do have that in there now, but it doesnt output anything to that file